# PHP 7 return 500 server error. Not reporting any errors

Tags: php, iis, php-7

PHP 7 does not return any errors only server error 500. I set error reporting to development machine but error file/screen is still empty. For example:

`echo 'test';` output is test
but `ech 'test';` (incorect) returns server error 500
i have tried already:

```
ini_set('display_errors',true);
```

and

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

but nothing happens.

```
IIS8
PHP7
```

Comment: show your php log `tailf -100 /patch/to/log/php.error.log`

Comment: @Naumov ? C:\Windows\Temp\php-7.0.7_errors.log

Comment: If you don't setup virtualhost, yes.

Comment: @Naumov file is in the right location

Comment: I don't know how to settings you apache, show php.ini in section `error` and apache.conf section `error.log`. And read you php error log, maybe you can make error in `ini_set`  instruction.

Comment: @Naumov this is not apache server i'm using IIS

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue too, upgrading from the IIS supported 5.x to 7.0.9.  Here's the trick.  By default the php.ini in 7.x does not have logging enabled:

1)  Create a blank file with write permissions from IIS (IUSR in Windows 10)

2)  Edit your php.ini and remove the semicolon ';' and update the error_log variable:

```
; Log errors to specified file. PHP's default behavior is to leave this value
; empty.
; http://php.net/error-log
; Example:
error_log = C:\path\to\file\errors.log
; Log errors to syslog (Event Log on Windows).
;error_log = syslog
```

3)  Restart IIS service using IIS manager